# PHP/ multipage with upload

Tags: mysql, upload, insert, refresh, duplicates

I have built a multipage form and 2 tables as follows:

Table1 - listings.
Table2 - attachments.

Page1 - the user selects a category
page2 - a MYSQL insert query is executed that creates a record in the listings table. The user enters the title, description, uploads an attachment and clicks submit. The upload button will open a page that allows the user to upload an attachment. Uploading an attachment will upload the file and insert a record in the attachments table.

page3 - a MYSQL update query is executed to update the listing record with the title and description.

I know this is not the best setup, but I have this way because I need the record number from the listing record to add to the attachment record. Everything functions properly. The issue I have is on page 2. If the user refreshes the page, duplicate records are inserted in the listings table. 
How can I stop the INSERT query from being re-executed on refresh?
If you think I need to change the entire setup, I am open for recommendations.

Thank you.

Comment: can you mention the language used?

Answer (score 0):

just create a unique index on your listing table in your database which would would identify it's uniqueness in this way your MySQL database will avoid to insert another value and return an error if the user try to insert the same value in this manner you could then control your application to do another action when the error occurs on the insertion of the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Define a session in the second page

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['flag'])!=1)
    {   
       mysql_query($query);
       $_SESSION['flag']='1';
    }
?>
```

IMPORTANT:Remember to unset the session in page1

```
session_start();
session_unset();
```